# Can i install "jupiter-support-eee" package on non eee laptop?

Tags: power-management, eeepc, jupiter

I have installed "Jupiter" on my Sony VAIO VPCZ2 laptop. it is very useful for me. I want to know what is the functionality of "jupiter-support-eee" package? is it only for eee netbook? can i install it on my laptop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if "jupiter-support-eee" is intended only for EeePC's.

**From [an article on OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/02/jupiter-awesome-netbook-powerconfig-applet):**

**EeePC netbooks that have the addition jupiter-support-eee package installed can also benefit from the following extra features: -*

1. *Super Hybrid Engine*
2. *GMA Overclock*

Comment: Do you have some experience about it?

Comment: Not personally, no. But the Super Hybrid Engine is an ASUS-specific technology (see this page: http://www.asus.com/Eee/Features/Super_Hybrid_Engine/), so that feature of jupiter-support-eee would be of little-to-no use on a non-ASUS laptop. I am unsure about the GMA Overclock feature, but my suspicion is that it also works by "talking" to a certain module or piece of firmware that would only be present on an EeePC.